# Call function in HTML page when SWF reaches frame number

Tags: javascript, html, flash

Does anyone know of the simplest way to start a function when an embedded OBJECT SWF file reaches a specific frame?  I have seen some pretty long answers with actionscript, was looking for something simple.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a lengthy ActionScript code. It may be just a single line. Place the following line in the frame ActionScript code:

```
ExternalInterface.call("FrameEntered");
```

It will invoke a JavaScript function named FrameEntered in your HTML page which you can declare like this:

```
function FrameEntered() {
    alert("FrameEntered")
}
```

NB: If you want to test it from a HTML file loaded from disk, you need to add the HTML file to the list of Flash Player trusted locations (right click  a player, then choose Global Settings/Advanced/Trusted Location Settings). No such configuration is needed if your HTML page is loaded from a website.

Comment: Thanks Mark!  Excellent piece of advice about the global settings. It was getting annoying having to post live every time!